# Export Methods for SugarCRM v10 api

Tags: python, api, sugarcrm

I am trying to make a call to the SugarCRM v10 api to get the output of a report without having to log into the web interface and click the export button.  I would like to get this report as data that can be written into csv format using python and the requests library.

I can authenticate successfully and get a token but whatever I try all I get as a response from reports is Error Method does not exist, by which they mean that you cannot use /csv at the end of the second url in this code block.

```
url = "https://mydomain.sugarondemand.com/rest/v10/oauth2/token"
payload = {"grant_type":"password","username":"ursername","password":"password","client_id":"sugar", "platform":"myspecialapp"}


r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))

response = json.loads(r.text)

token = response[u'access_token']    
print 'Success! OAuth token is ' + token

#What export methods are available? ###################################

#WRONG url = "https://mydomain.sugarondemand.com/rest/v10/Reports/report_id/csv"
#Following paquino's suggestion I used Base64

url = "https://mydomain.sugarondemand.com/rest/v10/Reports/report_id/Base64"
headers = { "Content-Type" : "application/json", "OAuth-Token": token }

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers);

response = r.text.decode('base64')

print response`
```

My question is this:  what Export Methods are available via an api call to v10 of the SugarCRM api.

Edit:  Using Base64 in the request url unfortunately returns ab object that I don't know how to parse...

```
%PDF-1.7
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 792.00 612.00]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 37217>>
stream
8.cÜ¬R≈`ä║dàQöWºáW╙µ
```

Comment: paquino's reply was helpful...

Comment: Is there a Python library that interacts with Sugarcrm v10 rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reports Api accepts "Base64" and "Pdf"

Comment: Well my assumption that Base64 would work to produce an output that can be written to csv didn't pan out unfortunately.   The output just turns out to be...
%PDF-1.7
3 0 obj
<</Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 792.00 612.00]
/Resources 2 0 R
/Contents 4 0 R>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<</Length 37217>>
stream

Comment: @pythagorean Yes the Base64 export type is actually just the PDF file as a string encoded in Base64.
Your other options to get this data off SugarCRM is to extend the Reports API to accept a CSV export. or to pull the relevant data through the module API.

Comment: Thanks yes I get that now.  I was hoping the "report" was going to just give me the data in the report but no it literally gives you that object...  "the report" as a pdf file.  Not super useful but looking over the documentation I see that they have explained how to extend the Reports API.

Comment: @ user1376214 I wanted to check if you were able to export a report successfully? I have a similar question 60702485 and was wondering if you solved it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### **Python Wrapper for SugarCRM REST API v10**

https://github.com/Feverup/pysugarcrm

**Quickstart**

```
pip install pysugarcrm
```

---

```
from pysugarcrm import SugarCRM
api = SugarCRM('https://yourdomain.sugaropencloud.e', 'youruser', 'yourpassword')

# Return info about current user
api.me

# A more complex query requesting employees
api.get('/Employees', query_params={'max_num': 2, 'offset': 2, 'fields': 'user_name,email'})

{'next_offset': 4,
 'records': [{'_acl': {'fields': {}},
   '_module': 'Employees',
   'date_modified': '2015-09-09T13:40:32+02:00',
   'email': [{'email_address': 'John.doe@domain.com',
     'invalid_email': False,
     'opt_out': False,
     'primary_address': True,
     'reply_to_address': False}],
   'id': '12364218-7d79-80e0-4f6d-35ed99a8419d',
   'user_name': 'john.doe'},
  {'_acl': {'fields': {}},
   '_module': 'Employees',
   'date_modified': '2015-09-09T13:39:54+02:00',
   'email': [{'email_address': 'alice@domain.com',
     'invalid_email': False,
     'opt_out': False,
     'primary_address': True,
     'reply_to_address': False}],
   'id': 'a0e117c0-9e46-aebf-f71a-55ed9a2b4731',
   'user_name': 'alice'}]}

# Generate a Lead
api.post('/Leads', json={'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'business_name_c': 'Test John', 'contact_email_c': 'john@smith.com'})
```

---

```
from pysugarcrm import sugar_api

with sugar_api('http://testserver.com/', "admin", "12345") as api:
    data = api.get('/Employees', query_params={'max_num': 2, 'offset': 2, 'fields': 'user_name,email'})
    api.post('/Leads', json={'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Smith', 'business_name_c': 'Test John', 'contact_email_c': 'john@smith.com'})

# Once we exit the context manager the sugar connection is closed and the user is logged out
```